# Hydra does not display the right answer in DVWA

Tags: brute-force, hydra, dvwa

I have been trying for days now to use Hydra in an attempt to crack DVWA brute force but to no avail, I am using the correct session cookie and to my knowledge have the correct syntax?

Query is:

```
hydra 127.0.0.1 -l admin -P /usr/share/set/src/fasttrack/wordlist.txt http-get-form "/DVWA/vulnerabilites/brute/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username and/or password incorrect.:H=Cookie: security=low;PHPSESSID=4m58apmmrijdonaib95nac6ld7"
```

Output is
[image]

I do know it can find my password list however I am unsure if it is correctly finding the page to brute force on, desperate for a fix!

Comment: 16 valid passwords found suggests it thinks each attempt is successful. Have you tried reducing your match string to "password incorrect"?

Comment: yeah I believe that it might not be hitting the correct page or area, I tried that by shortening the denial query but no cigar

Comment: And the case is correct? It might be worth trying a success match to attempt to work out what page its hitting. I.e if ":S=This is only on the home page". Alternatively if you have enough knowledge of the underlying protocols i'd suggest using something like wireshark to see exactly what is being sent.

Comment: Yeah I believe the case is correct, I tried hardcoding the query to debug, first with the incorrect password in the -P password section and the second being the correct password so one would think that it is hitting the correct page. error that comes back on the incorrect password is [ERROR] File for passwords not found: password1

Comment: I can't do any checking myself, but shouldn't the match string be in quotes so with " "? Not sure though

Comment: Yeah sadly this doesn't work, I believe now through testing various ftps and the like that this is a problem with **DVWA** and not with Hydra itself, sorry to bother everyone

Comment: Hydra gives a lot of false positive, at least this is my experience with it. You can try to use wfuzz instead.

https://wfuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/basicusage.html